# Kivy won't listen to "fulllscreen" setting

Tags: raspbian, python

Working on a Raspberry Pi Model 3 B, running raspbian.
Running Kivy v1.9.2-dev0 and Python v2.7.3

Trying out one of the Kivy [examples](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html) but for some reason the application won't come up in "Windowed mode". Therefore the application comes out in a 'stretched' appearance.

The code being executed:

```
from kivy.config import Config
# seems to be ignoring all of the below config settings
#Config.set('graphics','fullscreen','0')
Config.set('graphics','fullscreen','auto')
#Config.set('graphics','show_cursor','0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):


        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
                self.cols = 4
                #self.rows = 4
                self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
                self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
                self.add_widget(self.username)
                self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
                self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
                self.add_widget(self.password)





class MyApp(App):


        def build(self):
                return LoginScreen()
                #return Label(text='Hello world')




if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp().run()
```

I get the following output at the terminal when I execute 'python main.py:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-11-12_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

** (main.py:3118): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-9tGlyRrjWv: Connection refused
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: gtk3(['clipboard_dbusklipper'] ignored)
xclip version 0.12
Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Kim Saunders et al.
Distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL
[INFO   ] [Cutbuffer   ] Provider: xclip
[INFO   ] [CutBuffer   ] cut buffer support enabled
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event1
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event1>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event2
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event2>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event3
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event3>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <NOVATEK USB Keyboard>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <NOVATEK USB Keyboard>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <PixArt USB Optical Mouse>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <FT5406 memory based driver>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <FT5406 memory based driver> range ABS X position is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <FT5406 memory based driver> range ABS Y position is 0 - 480
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <FT5406 memory based driver> range position X is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <FT5406 memory based driver> range position Y is 0 - 480
```

Answer (score 0):

The closed source GLES driver doesn't support rendering in a window, so the app is always forced fullscreen.  For windowed rendering, you need to switch to the open source graphics driver (raspi-config's "OpenGL driver" option)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the rid of those black strip by adding `Config.set('graphics','window_state'_'maximized'` just after the fullscreen call. the whole code looks like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')
Config.write()
YourApp().run()
```